# iPhone - Clicking on navigation bar's back button doesn't change view

Tags: iphone

Never faced this issue before. I am using a navigation controller in my app. The app uses web services to get the data. If I go ahead 2 views and before the current view finishes loading, if I click the back button, the top bar changes as expected but the view does not.

The view remains the same.

This does not happen every time but most of the times I can reproduce this.

Any idea why this happens?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem once.  Have you verified that the viewDidAppear method is being called in the view that you've gone back too? Akso, are you using a straight UINavigationController, or have you created a subclass?

In my case, I was able to resolve the issue by explicitly calling viewDidAppear in the subView from the UINavigationView.  There's some discussion of the issue here: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1529769&tstart=0

Comment: Not using a subclass of navcontroller. I am using the class directly. And yes I did verify viewWillAppear gets called when I press the back button. After the issue happens, the viewControllers array of the navigationController has the wrong count. So the controllers just seem to disappear!

Comment: Are you calling Pop or using the back button to call it automatically?  Are you releasing anything in didReceiveMemoryWarning?